# Can emacs update itself

Tags: upgrade

Can Emacs update itself?  (with user action or automatically does not matter)

Is it possible to hit a chord or a `M-x emacs-update` like function to update to a desired version of Emacs or to the latest? Is there such a feature built-in or through a package?

Is it even possbile?

Comment: Apart from that possbilities would be interesting. One can set it to check for updates on startup and ask user to apply it or only download or download and apply updates based on a set of settings.

Comment: I do not know of any built-in function, but you could create a build script and build Emacs to your own specs, and then replace the current installation or install the new build to a different location.  E.g., building from the master branch each day.  Some builds of the master branch will fail, but please feel free to participate in the development with helpful feedback to the appropriate locations / persons interested.  I use Emacs to build from the master branch, or from the public stable version releases, whatever the need may be ...  The stable public version releases are infrequent.

Comment: The answer is no. This only really matters on Windows where the install process is not always automatic. If you use MSYS2 however, Emacs will update automatically whenever you run pacman -Syu.

Comment: @RaoulComninos what is MSYS2? I did not get the pacman part very good?

Comment: @lawlist That can be packed in an emcas lips package maybe, that would be nice. I know Lisp but not EmacsLisp. If I learn enough of it I would have a go for writing a package.